# Easiest way to use objects as filters for queries

Tags: design-patterns

I'm just starting on a new little pet project of mine. I started the project using a familiar pattern for using objects as "filters" in SQL Queries. I've never been much happy about its easy of use, but eventually more or less accepted it after having it drilled into my head by colleagues.

The example below hopefully highlights my concern. Especially in regards of sheer size. However that being said, I also see the strengths of this pattern which may put it in favor of continued use.

I'm looking for some opinions if I should continue as I always have or if there indeed is an easier way to do this. Either by using a different pattern or somehow "automate" the process.

*Please note that the below is only an example and isn't in use.*

```
public static User getUser(User filter) throws UserControllerException {
    String sql, sqlFilter = "";
    User user = null;

    try {
        Connection con = DataSource.getInstance().getConnection();

        if (filter.getCorp() != null) sqlFilter += " AND corp_id = ?";
        if (!filter.isNew()) sqlFilter += " AND user_id = ?";
        if (filter.getUsername() != null) sqlFilter += " AND username = ?";
        if (filter.getPasswordHash() != null) sqlFilter += " AND password_hash = ?";
        if (filter.getFirstName() != null) sqlFilter += " AND first_name = ?";
        if (filter.getLastName() != null) sqlFilter += " AND last_name = ?";
        if (filter.getPhoneNumber() > 0) sqlFilter += " AND phone_number = ?";

        sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1 = 1 " + sqlFilter;

        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        int psPos = 0;

        if (filter.getCorp() != null) ps.setLong(++psPos, filter.getCorp().getCorpId());;
        if (!filter.isNew()) ps.setLong(++psPos, filter.getUserId());
        if (filter.getUsername() != null) ps.setString(++psPos, filter.getUsername());
        if (filter.getPasswordHash() != null) ps.setString(++psPos, filter.getPasswordHash());
        if (filter.getFirstName() != null) ps.setString(++psPos, filter.getFirstName());
        if (filter.getLastName() != null) ps.setString(++psPos, filter.getLastName());
        if (filter.getPhoneNumber() > 0) ps.setLong(++psPos, filter.getPhoneNumber());

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            user = new User(
                    rs.getLong("user_id"),
                    new Corporation(rs.getLong("corp_id"), null),
                    rs.getString("username"),
                    rs.getString("password_hash"),
                    rs.getString("first_name"),
                    rs.getString("last_name"),
                    rs.getLong("phone_number")
            );
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UserControllerException(e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new UserControllerException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return user;
}
```

Comment: Is your question essentially how to collapse all those `if` statements?

Comment: Sure, that alone would probably help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by building your filter SQL String within the `filter` object itself (i.e. writing a `GetSqlFilter()` method on the `Filter` class), so that you have access to `Filter`'s internal members, without having to call all those member functions.

Comment: Mmm, this thought has crossed my mind and is probably what I'll end up doing if I stick to this pattern.

Comment: I'll let this one hang a bit longer in case other suggestions pop up.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, so marking this one as accepted. Not quite what I wished for, but probably as close as I am going to get.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get the various properties and fields into a list, cycle through the list, and determine the correct output for your filter statement. Reflection is slow compared to directly retrieving a property, accessing the internal members of your class, or accessing fields.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've been entertaining this thought as well. However, as you are mentioning, reflection is (so) slow that it's not really viable.